# Extract word-space from PDF documents

Tags: python, pdf

I am working on a assignment of detect hidden message in a PDF documents useing word-space shift method. In order to do that I need a python package that can help me to get the exactly space value between any word but I have not found any package. Anyone know any package can do that ? Thanks you. Example:
    Input:
This_is__a_simple_sentence_with__no_meaning"
    Output:
[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1]

For visual view, I assume each underscore present a space and each space equal 1. As you can see the total number of space between each word are not equal, some have more than one space between. What I try to archive here is output an array content only the total value of space between each words.

Comment: Could you give an example and expected output?

Comment: @MegaIng it will be an array of word-space in pt unit. If I have a sentence like this: "Hello from  python 3", the output would be [8, 16, 8], because the default spaceing is 8pt but between "from" and "python" there are two space so it would be 16

Comment: I don't at all understand what you want. Please add an example file and am example output to your question.

Comment: @MegaIng I have edit my question with an example, thanks you

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: You are aware that space between words is not necessarily generated by space characters alone? Sometimes not even space characters at all?

Comment: @mkl I know it but I only want simple example. In real example the space can be very very small that cannot be see. But the value of that space still different

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you want:

```
def count_spaces(s):
    l = []
    current = None
    for c in s:
        if c ==" ":
            if current is not None:
                current+=1
            else:
                current = 1
        else:
            if current is not None:
                l.append(current)
                current = None
    return l
```